# Government subsidies or tzedoko

Tags: halacha, gentiles, tzedakah-charity, priorities, politics-government

it is preferable not to take charity from non-Jews (maybe only if it is not in private)

Source [Yore daiya 254](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.254)

In a case of need (someone needs money for housing and/or food),
**which is more preferable**:
1. To take/collect *tsedoko* from Jews
 or
2. To get subsidies from the non-Jewish government (e.g. Section 8 or food stamps) not a private non-Jew, but probably considered in public, maybe also Jewish since Jews pay taxes

Sources on subject would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
To fulfill the request of the Honorable  @IsaacMoses bellow (sorry for being so slow)

254.1

> אָסוּר לְיִשְׂרָאֵל לִטֹּל צְדָקָה מִן הָעוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים בְּפַרְהֶסְיָא.  וְאִם אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לִחְיוֹת בַּצְּדָקָה שֶׁל יִשְׂרָאֵל, וְאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לִטְּלָהּ מֵהָעוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים בְּצִנְעָא, הֲרֵי זֶה מֻתָּר.
>   **It is forbidden to take tsedoko publicly from a non Jew**, unless you can't other ways, from a Jew or privately.

So it would seem it is preferable to collect tzedoka from Jews (option one)
254.2

> מֶלֶךְ אוֹ שַׂר עוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים שֶׁשָּׁלַח מָמוֹן לְיִשְׂרָאֵל לִצְדָקָה, אֵין מַחֲזִירִין אוֹתוֹ מִשּׁוּם שְׁלוֹם מַלְכוּת, אֶלָא נוֹטְלִין מִמֶּנּוּ וְיִנָּתֵן לַעֲנִיֵי נָכְרִים בַּסֶתֶר, כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא יִשְׁמַע הַמֶּלֶךְ. הַגָּה: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּיַעֲשֶׂה בָּהֶן מַה שֶּׁצִּוָּה לוֹ הַמּוֹשֵׁל...
>   If the king sends money for Jews **for tzedoko**  we should not return it for peace with the government but we should give is secretly to poor non-Jews, so that the kind will not hear about it **haga** there are those that say that you should do with them (the money) as the king says (give it to poor Jews)

It still seems to me that option one is preferred since the government is not sending the money but offering you to request it (by filling out a form)

But I am asking this question because I know of Orthodox Jews that do it and do not collect tzedoka from Jews at all, so maybe there is something I am not understanding correctly

Comment: Any reason to assume that the Shulhan Arukh refers to non-Jews in general? The cited source only speaks of idolaters.

Comment: @mevaqesh yes it is known that the word idolator was used instead of non-jew becouse of the cencers, any reason to believe not?

Comment: @hazoriz Oftentimes there are halakic differences between non-Jews and idolaters. Sometimes the former is swapped for the latter due to censorship. Sometimes it is used deliberately. Therefore, quoting the former and assuming the latter intent, without demonstrating this based on the original sources, makes for a very poor question.

Answer (score 1):

In a video by min 8:30 https://vimeo.com/142972789
Rabbi Moshe Heinamann sais it is permitted since the government do it for themselves, or since the money that is given is given by force (taxes) and not tzedoko

I have a question on the first reason this since in the end of the first perek in tanya it sais that all the kindness they do for themselves anyway, if so then what is the law about

Comment: "since the government do it for themselves" what does that mean?

Comment: Maybe Rabbi Heinemann does not agree with the Tanya.

Comment: @mevaqesh so that the people without income should not steel (this same money) this is how I understood it

Comment: Did he actually give that explanation about stealing?

Comment: @mevaqesh that is how I understand on minute 8:44

Comment: Your summary of the two **seems** to say that Rav Heinn=emann agrees witht he Tanya. That is giving tzedaka (to the Jews) is for the same reason the government does any kindness - for their own purposes (such as buying votes). This is like the gemara about the Romans building roads and bridges.

Comment: @sabbahillel So how to understand the halocho not to take from them, (when should we not take from them?)

Comment: @hazoriz Perhaps since the "king" has taken the taxes from Jews as well, it is regarded as a way of preventing the money from having been thrown away for nothin. However, this is just a guess and i do not have a source.

Comment: @sabbahillel sorry, I do not understand

Comment: @hazoriz Sorry. I meant that those who take from the government might regard it as a way of preventing money taken from Jews being thrown away for nothing. If the money comes from non-Jews then this would not apply. In that case, people should not take it if possible.

Comment: @sabbahillel Your reason is different then Rabbi heinamann's

Comment: @hazoriz Not necessarily, but I have not heard exactly what he said and do not know enough to go into it in detail.