# Accepting charity from a non-Jew

Tags: gentiles, tzedakah-charity

If a person sends out a group email to solicit funds to help needy families and ***inadvertently*** includes non-Jews on the email - Is it permitted to use the funds that the non-Jews donate towards helping needy Jewish families ?

I have read several articles on this subject but I am not clear in this case because:

- There was no intent to solicit directly from non-Jews
- The person is only an intermediary and the money goes to a third-party to distribute

I am not sure if the following makes a difference but:

- The money was already accepted (darkei shalom)
- the funds are not for a specific goal i.e. "give 10$ so we can buy a chicken for Yom Tov" rather the money is being collected  and given to  a Gabbai Tzdekah to distribute it as they see fit.

For those who are unfamiliar with the concept of accepting Tzedakla from a non-Jew please see this [Mi Yodea post for more information](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66089/government-subsidies-or-tzedoko)

Comment: Regarding darkei Shalom the goy will not be upset it you give his money to a poor goy

Comment: I'm missing something, here. Where or why is it forbidden to accept money from non-Jews?

Comment: @DanF Baba Batra 10

Comment: It would help your question if you gave a source behind taking tzedaka from a non Jew being usser

Comment: @Dude done. see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66089/government-subsidies-or-tzedoko

Answer (score 1):

There are Rabbi's that permit it but from the simple reading of the [Shulchan Aruch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66089/5120) it seems you should give it to poor non-Jews in such a case

Unless they have no other choice (they really need the money)

Unless no one knows that you got it from the non-Jew (so it is not public)

Comment: "There are Rabbi's that permit it" who?

Comment: @mevaqesh the rabbis of the synagogues that accept it (as is seen in the news)

Comment: perhaps edit this into the answer e.g. "I know there are rabbis who permit it because I saw them on the news".

Comment: @mevaqesh bechavod you can do that thank you

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely. Most non-Jews today are under the din of ger toshav(yes, even though there is no Yovel). See Rabbi Soloveitchik, Od Yisrael Yoseph Beni Chai, Siman 3

Comment: Is that in Israel or in all countries?