# Donations from non-Jews

Tags: gentiles, tzedakah-charity, sefer-torah

Are donations to Torah institutions from non-Jews acceptable?

Does it make a difference if they donate money or objects (e.g. a sefer Torah)? Does it make a difference who the donor is and what their intentions are? Are there cases where donations from non-Jews are accepted?

Comment: @mbloch the way you've edited it how, it seems like https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70500 , no?

Comment: See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah siman 254.

Comment: [MT Matanot Aniyim 8:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/986709/jewish/Matnot-Aniyim-Chapter-8.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Of course they are acceptable if the gentile sincerely wants to donate toward a Torah cause. The Passuk says that a Gentile can bring a Sacrifice to the Beth Hamikdosh see Nazir 62a

> איש איש לרבות את העובדי כוכבים שהן נודרים נדרים ונדבות כישראל

We know Herod rebuilt the Beth Hamikdosh through the advice of Bava Ben Buta even though he was an Ever Cnaani (though one may argue he was obligated to do Mitzvos like a woman anyway see Bava Basra 3b-4a).

However it is not our job to expect anything from them or push them to give Bava Basra 4a:

> אמר רב ואיתימא ר' יהושע בן לוי מפני מה נענש דניאל מפני שהשיא עצה לנבוכדנצר שנאמר (דניאל ד, כד) להן מלכא מלכי ישפר עלך וחטאיך בצדקה פרוק ועויתך במיחן עניין הן תהוי ארכא לשלותך 
>    Rambam:https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%97_%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%98%D7%95

Comment: Although tzedaka is similar to sacrifices, they are not the same. See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 254 about tzedaka from gentiles. The institutions that do accept donations don't have on what to rely on(at least I haven't seen any sources permitting it).

Comment: How do you know Herod was an Eved Knani? I thought he was descended from Edomite converts, and was a full-fledged Jew.

Comment: @ezra sorry it wasn't clear but it's mentioned in Bava Basra 4a that I quoted

Comment: @chachamnisan Sa yd 254,2 עובד כוכבים ששלח ממון לישראל לצדקה אין מחזירין אותו משום שלום מלכות that fits with my post

Comment: @yosefkorn It says מֶלֶךְ אוֹ שַׂר עוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים; don't post only what fits. Your answer is incorrect and encourages a forbidden practice.

Comment: @chachamnissan no it does not say that, anyone can verify that you are incorect. it does not say melech o sar

Comment: @yosefkorn I cut and pasted it...